# What's the meaning of "that" in 'They came, in such great numbers that before night he had only twopence left for himself.'?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> The prince said 'Go bury the dead, and let his creditors come to my
>   lodging, and there their debts shall be paid.' They came, in such
>   great numbers **that** before night he had only twopence left for himself.

This is from English fairy tales. I can't understand the meaning of "that". Does this "that" mean "their debts"? If so, I wonder it needs "of" like "in such great numbers of that". Or is it other meaning?

Comment: It means [*so that*](http://www.yourdictionary.com/so-that). In this case, it is introducing an effect. Because they came in such great numbers, he only had twopence left for himself.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Can I omit "so"?

Comment: Can you omit "so" from what? You can say "I had such a large number of telephone calls that I was not able to get any work done." Using "so that" in this case would sound awkward. I can't explain the rules, I'm afraid.

Comment: You said it means "so that", so I thought this "that" is "that" omitted "so". Is the usage of "so that" and "that" same?

Comment: No. They are not the same. It's just the only way that I could think of to describe this particular usage of *that*. Hopefully, someone else can do a better job than me.

Comment: Yuuichi: What @Mick means is that ***such** that = so that*. In your example, *They came in numbers **so great that** [something was caused to happen].*

Comment: Ah, I got it. I didn't know the word "such that" but I learn now.

Comment: It has no meaning, and it is not omissible. It is a meaningless subordinator whose function is to introduce the subordinate content clause 'that before night he had only twopence left for himself' .The adverb 'such' licenses the content clause which expresses the result of them coming in such great numbers.

Answer (score 2):

As Mick said, it is introducing an effect:

> They came so quickly and in such great numbers, to have him pay their debts, that before night he had only twopence left for himself.
>
> The approaching wave hit with such force that it broke the dyke.
>
> Her scream was so loud and high pitched that it shattered windows a half mile away.
>
> He used so many words that by the time he was finished, he'd run out of them entirely.

That's what the word that does, unless you're using it like that. Is that clear enough? (Wow, isn't that something; English is quite a beast. And that's that.)

Comment: "He used so many words that by the time he was finished, he'd run out of them entirely." I know exactly how *that* feels. Well done!

Comment: "That" is a meaningless subordinator whose function is to introduce the subordinate content clause _that before night he had only twopence left for himself_ .The adverb 'such' licenses the content clause which expresses the result of them coming in such great numbers.